# What's the biblical basis for Abraham, David, etc. to be raised in the first resurrection?

Tags: resurrection, abraham, david

We are told David is dead.

> For David, after he had served God’s purpose in his own generation, fell asleep, and was buried among his fathers and underwent decay Acts 13:36

We could include any of 'God's men and women of old' in this - Moses, the prophets etc. Whenever one of these OT servants is raised, we would assume they will be raised together. We also are told that Moses and Elijah were presented in a *vision* on the mount with Jesus and the voice of God and were not actually alive at this time.

And as they are coming down from the mount, Jesus charged them, saying, 'Say to no one the vision, till the Son of Man out of the dead may rise.' Matt 17:9 Youngs, NASB, BLB

Do we have firm indication that these servants before Jesus will be raised with the saints at his return?

Comment: There is considerable diversity as to the views of 1. The actual proceedings in the resurrection 2. Whether there is one general resurrection or two. 3. Whether Moses and Elijah were physically present at the Transfiguration of Jesus 4. That Jesus can be considered as 'servant' along with such as Moses etc. Therefore I would think that the question needs to be scoped.

Comment: Oh that my words were now written! oh that they were printed in a book! That they were graven with an iron pen and lead in the rock for ever! For I know that my redeemer liveth, and that he shall stand at the latter day upon the earth: And though after my skin worms destroy this body, yet in my flesh shall I see God: Whom I shall see for myself, and mine eyes shall behold, and not another; though my reins be consumed within me. - Job 19:23-27  They certainly had that hope!

Comment: @NigelJ your “considerable diversity” is caused by deviating from clear revelation. ‘Blessed and holy are those who share in the first resurrection’, requires only a simple reading to determine there must be more than one! All your protestations are addressed by the inspired text and need cause no confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David in particular is shown as resurrected and ruling here on Earth, following the tribulations of Day of the Lord:

> Alas! For that day is great, So that none is like it; And it is the time of Jacob’s trouble, But he shall be saved out of it.
> ‘For it shall come to pass in that day,’ Says the LORD of hosts, ‘That I will break his yoke from your neck, And will burst your bonds; Foreigners shall no more enslave them.
> But they shall serve the LORD their God, And **David their king, Whom I will raise up for them**.
> — Jeremiah 30:7–9

> “They shall not defile themselves anymore with their idols, nor with their detestable things, nor with any of their transgressions; but I will deliver them from all their dwelling places in which they have sinned, and will cleanse them. Then they shall be My people, and I will be their God.
> **David My servant shall be king** over them, and they shall all have one shepherd; they shall also walk in My judgments and observe My statutes, and do them.
> Then they shall dwell in the land that I have given to Jacob My servant, where your fathers dwelt; and they shall dwell there, they, their children, and their children’s children, forever; and **My servant David shall be their prince** forever.
> — Ezekiel 37:23–25

Jesus talked of this time:

> “And this is the will of Him who sent Me, that everyone who sees the Son and believes in Him may have everlasting life; and I will raise him up at **the last day**.”
> — John 6:40

As did Paul:

> And God both raised up the Lord and will also raise us up by His power.
> — 1 Corinthians 6:1

The Book of Revelation describes this same time as the "first resurrection", when *all* the saints will be transformed into immortal beings, ruling in the Kingdom of God:

> Blessed and holy is he who has part in the **first resurrection**. Over such the second death has no power, but they shall be priests of God and of Christ, and shall reign with Him a thousand years.
>
> But the rest of the dead did not live again until the thousand years were finished. This is the **first resurrection**.
> — Revelation 20:6,5